# {active, N} mode in erlang secure tcp

Tags: ssl, tcp, erlang

I write this simple code with ssltcp:

```
ssl:start().
{ok, ListenSocket} = ssl:listen(9999, [{certfile, "cert.pem"}, {keyfile, "key.pem"},{reuseaddr, true}]).
{ok, Socket} = ssl:transport_accept(ListenSocket).
ssl:ssl_accept(Socket).
ssl:setopts(Socket, [{active, once}]).
```

it works fine but when i replace `{active, once}` with `{active, 3}`, returns this error:

> {error,{options,{socket_options,{active,3}}}}

How can use `{active, N}` mode in secure tcp?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `{active,N}` mode is not implemented for SSL connections. I originally wrote the `{active,N}` mode and when I looked into possibly implementing it for SSL, I found that the way Erlang SSL sockets are implemented over the top of underlying TCP sockets involves changes on those sockets between active and passive modes as part of the protocol implementation, and so implementing `{active,N}` for SSL is not simply a matter of opening an underlying socket in that mode.

Comment: For reference, `{active, N}` was implemented for SSL/TLS in 2019 and released in OTP 21.3.